# jquery not working in my VS2013

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013

I have made following very simple code just to test few things.My following code is not working in my website project in VS2013 although it is working fine in jsfiddle.net.what is happening ?

**HTML:**

```
 <p>Name:</p>
    <input type="text" />
    <p>Age:</p>
    <input type="text" />
    <p></p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                window.alert("Hi Guys");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: you can't write code inside a script tag that already has an `src`, use another tag after you close the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        alert("Hi Guys");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please if u could also tell me how intellisense could work in a js file for jquery.Although there are some posts available but not working for me.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d9a69e8-38cf-4fe8-9c9f-271d03a19be1/visual-studio-2013-jquery-intellisense-not-fully-working?forum=wpdevelop and https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery-vsdoc/